# How can I set multiple Y axis in dygraph?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I love dygraph!

When adding multiple series in a chart, I don't know how to show multiple Y axis's.

I noticed there is an example: http://dygraphs.com/tests/value-axis-formatters.html, it has only 2 y axis, I modified the source code, adding axis's for Y1 and Y2, the axis are overlapping with each other on the left side.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your code look like?

To add multiple y-axes you need to put an axes argument where you put the rest --

```
axes: { y2: {} },
series: { "Series Name": { axis: 'y2' } }
```

Comment: Thanks, seems only support 2 y-axis.